# How to put a remote object to Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to put a remote object to amazon s3, i'm using this code :

```
$s3 = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory();
$bucket = getenv('S3_BUCKET')?: die('No "S3_BUCKET" config var in found in env!');


$s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => 'myvideo.mp4',
    'Body'   => 'http://example.fr/video.mp4'
));
```

this code is working but it's not uploading a full size file.

Comment: What do you mean when you're saying "not uploading a full size file"? Is anything being uploaded at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't do what you want:

```
'Body'   => 'http://example.fr/video.mp4'
```

This sets the object body to contain the *string* of the URL... not the content from the remote URL.

To upload a "remote" object, you have to download it first.  There is no built-in capability in S3 to fetch content from a remote URL.